# Auto-updating cell ranges based on date

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have an excel document with details of invoices on each row for nearly 5000 rows. These rows constantly have new invoices added to the bottom of them.

I am looking for a way to be able to assign the invoices that were raised within the previous month to a range prior to analysing them. There could be several invoices raised on the same day and they may not (although they should be) in order
The dates are within the first column of the workbook (A:A).

Having had a look around I thought I had come up with two solutions which created an auto extending named range but neither of them worked:

```
=OFFSET((DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,1)),0,0,COUNTA(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,1)):(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),1))
```

and

```
=OFFSET((DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,1)),0,0,COUNTA(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,1)):(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,31),1))
```

The reason that I am trying to get this to work with Name Manager and OFFSET is to use the named range within VBA so if anyone is aware of an easier way to do this within VBA that would also be great.

Comment: Have you looked at using Excel tables? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c

Comment: @a-burge From what I know about Excel Tables this would allow me to filter the most recent month manually and then select the displayed cells as the named range?

Although this would work to a degree, the macro that is utilising the named range functions in another document and I was looking to build in a long term solution. If I didn't go in every month to filter and select the correct month then the wrong data would be pulled and analysed.

Also if a row was then added with a date in the previous month after the manual filter then the range and data would be wrong.

Comment: I see your point. Reason I mention Excel Tables is that they resize dynamically and are fairly simple to manipulate through VBA in my opinion (e.g. by looping through to assess against a criteria (your filter) collect the results into a temporary array and then do whatever processing you want).

Comment: FWIW, I am unable to use your formulas, they seem to break at the semicolon for me.

Comment: Have you tried setting filter on your sheet? you could then use VBA to set the filter and copy the visible range. Although I'm not sure if you really need to copy if your filters are good for purpose

Comment: @a-burge After having a look around the ability to cycle through a Table and then assess them before setting as an integer in an array seems like it may be the way to go. Having not worked with arrays before (still picking up VBA as I go) would you have any sample code that I could work to try and modify?

Comment: @Zac Although not ideal, this could be an initial solution. How would I incorporate this? Using something like `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select`?

Comment: If you use Excel Table with a slicer added to filter added column which pulls month from invoice date, it would be very easy to change filter, and then, yes, use `SpecialCells()`